# Get tomcat-context.xml functionality in spring boot and look-up resource on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jndi, embedded-tomcat-7

In tomcat if we put context.xml file in META-INF folder tomcat create resource for us and we can lookup that resource. Here is my context file:

```
<Context>
  <Resource 
        name="jdbc/referenceData" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        description="Reference Data "
        username=" " 
        password="" 
        driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
        url=" "/>
</Context>
```

I am trying to get same functionality on spring-boot. I have overridden the following method of TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer:

```
            @Override
            protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                    Tomcat tomcat) {
                tomcat.enableNaming();                  

                return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
            }

            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
                resource.setAuth("Container");
                resource.setName("jdbc/referenceData");
                resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
                resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
                resource.setProperty("url", "url of jndi");
                resource.setProperty("password", "");
                resource.setProperty("username", "");
                context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);

            }
```

But the problem is I need to look-up this JNDI resource in configuration class (@Configuration annotated class). Here is the code when I look up this resource:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();        
(DataSource) ctx.lookup(referenceJndiName)
```

I get javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/referenceData] is not bound in this Context. Because @Configuration class called before tomcat is fully ready. I have tried to look up by "java:comp/env/jdbc/referenceData" but same result. I have also tried with application.properties file but no luck. Every time give the error: resource is not bound in this context.

Is there any way like cargo-maven2-plugin does: it can copy defined context.xml to context.xml.default of embaded tomcat. Is spring-boot-maven-plugin doing anything like that? Or can we load JNDI resource and look-up on startup?

Thanks for the time and any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. You solved?